# Ways to 'vectorize' this repetitive C++ code?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl

I saw [this code in a HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w16/challenges/devu-and-lucky-numbers/editorial) challenge solution, and I'm wondering whether there's a way to make it more efficient and/or aesthetically appealing. It's counting all the permutations of a bunch of digits, where there are `x 4's`, `y 5's`, and `z 6's`. For this reason, the code gets quite repetitive:

```
int cnt[101][101][101];

int solve1(int x,int y,int z){
    if(x <= 0 && y <= 0 && z <= 0)
        return 1 ;
    int &ret = cnt[x][y][z] ;
    if(ret != -1) return ret ;
    ret = 0 ;
    if(x)
        ret += solve1(x-1,y,z) ;
    if(ret >= mod) ret -= mod ; 
    if(y)
        ret += solve1(x,y-1,z) ;
    if(ret >= mod) ret -= mod ; 
    if(z)
        ret += solve1(x,y,z-1) ;
    if(ret >= mod) ret -= mod ; 
    return ret ;
}
```

**Do `STL` containers or algorithms offer a way to make this less repetitive and/or more efficient?**

Considered and rejected:
 Pass a `vector` to `solve()` rather than many integers and then use `accumulate` to collect `ret`
    while modifying each vector element (x, y, z as vector elements) and recalling `solve` on modified copy of original vector input.
    But this just creates a whole bunch of `vectors` without any clear
    counterbalancing improvement. Also, I haven't thought out the `accumulate` application so presumably that part is way off/not possible.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I haven't checked the code. But the problem as you described has a closed form solution. Would that be efficient and aesthetically appealing enough?

Comment: @NicoSchertler Sure I'd like to see it. Do you have link/name for the problem?

Comment: If I understand correctly, it is a permutation with repetition. The number of permutations would be `(x+y+z)!/(x!*y!*z!)`. It still requires a bit of thinking to make the computation efficient (without having to calculate every factorial).

Comment: @NicoSchertler You are correct, I know this formula actually. But I have another function where this formula can't be used (adding actual results of permutation), so the question still stands.

Comment: The above is symmetric in xyz -- so sort the 3 before solving each step.  Should be way faster, less wasted computations.

Comment: @Yakk I don't think that's true. x, y, and z each correspond to different digits (4, 5, and 6), but maybe I am misunderstanding you. Can you be more explicit?

Comment: @sunny `solve1(1,2,3)==solve1(3,2,1)` -- the algorithm is symmetric.  So we can improve cache hit rate by always doing lookup with `x<=y<=z`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With c++11, you can replace:

```
if(x)
    ret += solve1(x-1,y,z) ;
if(ret >= mod) ret -= mod ; 
if(y)
    ret += solve1(x,y-1,z) ;
if(ret >= mod) ret -= mod ; 
if(z)
    ret += solve1(x,y,z-1) ;
if(ret >= mod) ret -= mod ;
```

With:

```
auto func = [](int&ret, int x, int y, int z)
{
    ret += solve1(x, y, z);
    if (ret >= mod) ret -= mod;
    return ret;
};
if (x) func (ret, x-1, y, z);
if (y) func (ret, x, y-1, z);
if (z) func (ret, x, y, z-1);
```

You could also just use a function.

Comment: Scott Meyers's C++ 11 book is on my to-do list, but I don't think my language skills are ready yet. Thanks a lot, this is exactly like what I was hoping was out there.

Comment: Another application for lambdas that I was unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the x y z, and the memoization is far more effective:

```
int cnt[101][101][101]={0};
int solve1(std::array<int,3> idx){
  std::sort(idx.begin(),idx.end());
  int x=idx[0],y=idx[1],z=idx[2];

  if(x <= 0 && y <= 0 && z <= 0) return 1;
  int &ret = cnt[x][y][z];
  if(ret != -1) return ret;
  ret = 0;
  auto f=[&](int x,int y,int z){
    ret += solve1({{x-1,y,z}});
    if(ret >= mod) ret -= mod;
  };
  if(x)f(x-1,y,z);
  if(y)f(x,y-1,z);
  if(z)f(x,y,z-1);
  return ret;
}
int solve1(int x,int y,int z){
  return solve1({{x,y,z}});
}
```